# React props and Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem I can not solve myself in relation to react.
What I am trying to do is add props to my Component
So I can use my compnent again and again just with a string relative to a variable so I can just write e.g.

I really searched for some different things but none that worked.

Just hoping you can get me on.

Hope it makes sense otherwise feel free to ask

My Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class UserSelections extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            DataisLoaded: false,

        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);


    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // ComponentDidMount is used to
    // execute the code
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(
            "URL")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({
                    items: json,
                    DataisLoaded: true
                });
            })
    }
    render() {
        const { DataisLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (!DataisLoaded) return <div>
            <h1> Vent et øjeblik... </h1> </div> ;

        return (
            <div className = "App">
                <h1> Fetch data from an api in react </h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label><select name={this.state.slug} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {                             --->Need Variable here<--- Down here 
                items.filter(slug => slug.slug === **'bygnings-st'**).map((item, index) => (

                        <option value={ item.outputvalue }  key={index}>{ item.outputvalue }</option>

                ))
            }</select>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

import React from "react";
import UserSelections from "./components/UserSelections";

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserSelections **Need props here** /> <-------------------
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Best regards
Morten

Comment: Can we rewrite your  class based component to  functional component ?

Comment: can you please tell me what kind of props are you trying to send

Comment: Hi Jasur I have tryed, but I think I not do it right. But you are more then welcome to try need all help I can get. I have struggled with this for a long time

Comment: Gardezi I don't have any because I not Kan get it to work, but I try from det front with props to but the string in til the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a string as prop:

```
 const value = "hi";
 <UserSelections stringProp={value} />
```

And you display the value with:

```
{this.props.stringProp}
```

inside of the UserSelections component

Comment: You pass the prop in this way:  <UserSelections stringProp={value} /> And you can user the value of "stringProp" inside the UserSelctions component, you access the value with "this.props.stringProp". You can change the name from "stringProp" to another one that describes better the info that you are passing.

Comment: Thank you so much that was the solution :-)

I am so happy now! learn so much :-)